# How do you say "Geek"/"nerd" in Russian?

Tags: перевод, одним-словом

Is there a way to express "geek"/"nerd" idiom in Russian without a whole paragraph describing what or who a nerd/geek is?

The only thing I can think of that would be culturally equivalent would be "очкарик" but semantically, the meaning is different even if there's some idiomatic overlap.

Comment: I wonder if these two words can be considered together at all. In my experience, a geek is someone keen about, overinterested in something, usually some technology: computer geek, Internet geek, LaTeX geek. So it just describes an attitude to something. On the contrary, a nerd is a social type of a person. S/he may not be especially interested in anything in particular.

Comment: @texnic, as an aside, English have gender neutral pronoun _they_ to use when the gender is ambiguous. There is no need to invent and use strange concoctions like _s/he_.

Comment: @texnic - yes, I'm quite familiar with nuances between geek and nerd. However, I'm unsure if a russian idiom (if any) exists for only one of them, or both at the same time, thus lumping both together

Comment: @theUg: I haven't of course invented this form (http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/s/he), but I do appreciate the reminder. I've spent the last five years in Germany, and they here do use a similar thing all the time _Mitarbeiter(in)_.

Comment: @texnic - This seems slightly more important in German due to Das/Der distinction, no?

Comment: No, it's rather due to the attitude of Germans' to the women's rights. By no means should you forget to address the beautiful part of the society :)

Comment: texnic - the phrase "women's rights" and the nation that invented "Kinder, Küche, Kirche" seem strange to appear in the same sentence :)

Comment: @DVK, it’s a bit more complicated than that. That mantra was promoted during earlier part of XX century by conservatives, because Socialist and Communist agenda of emancipation could be appealing to women, so that slogan represented conservative counter-movement, because everyone was afraid of Red Revolution (I am reading history books on society in pre-Nazi Germani right now, this topic was discussed). And by no means Germans are unique in that. After all, similar attitudes against emancipation and even education are expressed even in your US of A these days.

Comment: "nerd" = "ботан". for geek - "задрОт", do not use in official speech) friends only) it is from "дрочИть" = "masturbate"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Ботаник` looks like a good candidate. Often shortened to `ботан`.

Interestingly, Russian Wikipedia [links](http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%28%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) from `Ботаник` to `гик` and `нёрд`.

Comment: Botanik looks to be the closest. I don't think гик and нёрд are familiar to majority of non-nerdy population, though.

Comment: An explanation for the down vote is common courtesy.

Comment: In my opinion `Ботаник` is suitable for `nerd`, but not for `geek`. And word `гик` is widely used (in narrow communities) while `нерд/нёрд` is substituted with `ботаник`.

Answer (score 10):

While there are not direct equivalents to *geek*, and *nerd*, we can find some terms that can match them closely, depending on context.

- According to [OED definition](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/geek?q=geek), *geek* is “an unfashionable or socially inept person”, with the sub-sense of “a knowledgeable and *obsessive* enthusiast” (emphasis mine). If we stress the obsessiveness of that enthusiasm, then the translations ***чо́кнутый*** ([*cracked* **2.**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cracked?q=cracked), [*batty* <sup>1</sup>](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/batty?q=batty), also *тронутый* (*touched*)) and ***поме́шанный*** (*insane*; literally: *messed (up)*) often [given by on-line dictionaries](http://slovari.yandex.ru/geek/en/#lingvo/) are suitable. Moreover, they line up with original etymology of *geek* (“related to Dutch *gek* ‘mad, silly’”). But these words do not necessarily imply “social ineptitude”, although they are usually used with disapproval to describe someone who is way too much into something or someone.
- *Nerd*, who is [defined by OED](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nerd?q=nerd) as “a foolish or contemptible person who lacks social skills or is boringly studious”, is easy to match by the word ***бота́ник*** (literally: *botanist*, shortened as *ботан* or *бата́н*). Why this discipline of biology acquired such dubious distinction is unclear, but there is a version that looks more like a folk etymology (as I have not seen a serious source on the subject), but it actually makes sense.

  In 1825 classic of Russian literature, [Griboyedov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Griboyedov)’s satire [*Woe from Wit*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woe_from_Wit) (*Горе от ума*), there is a passage in Act III, where the Duchess talks about her nephew who is so involved in studying chemistry and botany that he is not interested in women or a career:

  > Нет, в Петербурге институт
  >   Пе-да-го-гический, так, кажется, зовут:
  >   Там упражняются в расколах и в безверьи,
  >   Профессоры!! — У них учился наш родня,
  >   И вышел! Хоть сейчас в аптеку, в подмастерьи.
  >   От женщин бегает, и даже от меня!
  >   Чинов не хочет знать! Он химик, он ботаник,
  >   Князь Фёдор, мой племянник.

  The word *очкарик* (one who wears glasses), while a good alternative, obviously limits its application to people whose sight had suffered from all that studying. On the contrary, why some dictionaries list *зануда* (*bore, pest*) as the first choice translation for *nerd* is beyond my comprehension. The word *умник*, while originally may have had a positive sense of someone who is laudably intelligent, now became to mean to address someone (usually in a form of exclamation) who is “too clever” and knows too much for their own good.

On a related topic, as a warning, while the word *ботаник* came to be strongly associated with nerdiness, the informal meaning of the word *химик* (*chemist*) and related slang verb *химичить* (“do chemistry”) are usually used to describe someone doing some inappropriately dangerous tinkering, messing things up.

Comment: умник is most accurately translated as "smarass" or "smart alec" IMHO.

Comment: @DVK, what I said.

Answer (score 9):

*Задрот* if you need strong negative connotation. That’s usually male, in his teens or older, with weird appearance and no girlfriend.

Comment: Задрот seems more correllated to gamers who play games over and over again. There is some overlap with geeks/nerds but only slight one.

Comment: @DVK, not necessarily gamers, but anyone doing something repeatedly. And, obviously, negative as it describes someone who masturbates awful lot.

Comment: that's both negative and incivil - literally, Задрот means wanker. then again, maybe that's what you want to say...

Comment: I'd say this is the most modern form. Other answers on this thread are also accurate, but tend to have been used more by older generations.

Answer (score 3):

"Зубрила" may be what you are looking for. Also "зануда" if you want negative connotation

Comment: зануда is kind of very different. More like wet blanket or downer equivalent.

Comment: @DVK, I touched on _зануда_ in my answer, but _зубрила_ is actually closer to home.

Answer (score 2):

It is worthwhile to note that if the text is addressed to young tech-savvy (and yeah, geeky) audience, the word `гик` will be understanded by most. There are almost 2 million mentions of the word found by Google.
However, the calque `нерд` or `нёрд` is used much less frequently, so translations suggested by other answers (`ботаник`, `ботан` or `задрот`, in the order of increasing negative connotation) should be used.

Comment: Hерд or нёрд is not a calque but a loanword.

Answer (score 0):

Как ни забавно, в русский язык уже вошло слово "гик" по кальке с английского. И молодежь очень часто пользуется именно им.

Comment: В принятом ответе об этом, в принципе, упомянули.

Comment: Возможно, не заметил.